# Is it possible to put a separate video on top of your main video?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

For blender video editing, I was wondering if it was possible to have my main video running and then for example another one of my own videos running at the same time that is smaller and only takes up the top corner of the screen.

So two videos running at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Select the second video strip in the *Sequencer*, and in the *N panel > Strip > Transform* change the *Position* and *Scale* values, or in the *Preview* window press <kbd>G</kbd> to move it and <kbd>S</kbd> to scale it manually:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. For some reason overlapping clips I can only see the new clip but not the old one. It just becomes gray background.

Comment: Alpha overlayer for those wondering